# How to put space the input word in a textfile in java

Tags: java, space

I have a problem when entering an input on the `jtextfield` because all the words are sticking with each other. I want to separate them in the form username and password in the textfile but they are sticking with each other. I don't know how to put spaces or put the password in the next line.

Here's my code so far:

```
package java_log_in;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;


public final class JAVA_FRAME {

    JFrame f=new JFrame("LOGIN PAGE");

    JLabel label=new JLabel("Enter Username");
    JTextField tf=new JTextField(20);

    JLabel label_2=new JLabel("Enter Email");
    JTextField tf_2=new JTextField(20);

    JButton button=new JButton("LOG IN");

    public JAVA_FRAME(){
         frame();
    }

    public void frame(){
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(250,250);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(tf);
        panel.add(label_2);
        panel.add(tf_2);
        panel.add(button);

        f.add(panel);

        event e=new event();
        button.addActionListener(e);
     }

     public class event implements ActionListener{

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             try {
                 String word=tf.getText();               
                 String words=tf_2.getText();  `            
                 FileWriter stream= new 
                 FileWriter("C://Users//Keyboard//Desktop//file.txt");
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(stream); 
                 out.write(word);
                 out.write(words);
                 out.close();
             } catch(Exception ex){}     
         }         
     }
}
```

Comment: out.write("Username: " + word + "\nPassword: " + words);

Comment: Thank you so much sir..I'll try your answer

Comment: I'd tried your answer sir but they still stuck with each other.

Comment: What operating system are you on? It is probably the editor you view it in, Notepad is not that good. If you want to see the space in a notepad use out.write("Username: " + word + System.lineSeperator() + "Password: " + words);

Comment: Thank you sir...And BTW I'm not using notepad I'm using netbeans IDE  and I tried ur suggestion and it work sir..Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

You are writing the data without spaces. Please add `out.write(" ")` between `out.write(word);` and `out.write(words);` for introducing space. For new line, it should be `out.newLine()` rather.

Comment: Ohh..OK sir I'll try your answer

Comment: Did you even try my comment?

Comment: @BlackLotus : You're welcome. If it answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than an answer since this is a duplicate question

Comment: @Dinh : Sorry. Did not know that it's a duplicate question. Is that why the answer got downvoted ?